# Visualisation in PYTHON[HELP]

Tags: python

I actually wanted to find a python code for creating an image which only consists the border of all the states of India. I have actually gone through a package named Canny Edge Detection which does the job. But it doesnt give the output with the borders with the white background..
  I actually needed the map border in white background because im planning on doing heat map over the obtained map.!

The code for Canny Edge Detection is :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('map.jpg',0)
edges = cv2.Canny(img,100,200)

plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Original Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(edges,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Edge Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.show()
```

Is there any other way to get the desired output ?

Answer (score 0):

The actual visualisation tool you're using is matplotlib, which is an incredibly versatile and powerful tool.  You should be able to further manipulate the plot after it is initially generated.  Take a look at the [matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/contents.html).